# Suggestion on Spring OAuth2 architecture

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build spring-angular2 (new to spring) application and I choose OAuth2 as security model. My new application has 3 parts. Auth Server, backend server and front end (angular 2). Currently I am using OAuth2 just for Authentication purpose

As per my current design, my server (business layer) will communicate with auth server for authentication (authorization_code based) and will receive OAuth2 token (short lived access token and longer lived refresh token). My intention here is to use this refresh token to generate access tokens whenever required till its expiry, after which, redirect to the auth server for login. All token management will be handled at server and front-end will not know anything about this.

Now with this design when I run my application, angular2 app will load first and it will try to access protected url (as auth check). If server return 401 error, angular will force webpage to redirect to auth server for login. Backend server uses session for handling security(default oauth2client settings). The problem here is that when session expires (default 30 mins) because of idling, I wont be able to use refresh token (10 days validity) and spring security will redirect webpage to auth server for login.

I think extending session validity to 10 days is not a good idea. So I am planning to avoid sessions from design, storing tokens in user model (db) and send some unique id to browser which would be used to accessing this token and create Authentication object using filter. Angular will store this id in localstorage and send in every request header.

Kindly let me know if I need to add anymore inputs to this question.

I need your advice on

1) whether this architecture is good? do you have any suggestions to improve this?

2) Is there any way, I can handle refresh token without worrying about session idle timeout? (As I mentioned earlier I am new to Spring world. So I might be missing something small here)

3) If I go sessionless, how do you suggest I should communicate unique id to browser(angular2)? I want to avoid cookies also. Is url query string only way to pass this unique value to angular app in this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Not related to Spring but for OAuth applications server side is not required as access token is a bearer token. But in your case, I guess you can make the refresh token limit to 25 minutes so that before your session idles out you get a new token but here again (If I have understood correctly) problem will be that your session will still timeout on server and user will still be redirected for authentication.

Logically your resource server should simply have a filter which validates the token either himself or with Authz Server and grants the access. NO SESSION management on server side. Also, Please consider the logout scenarios.

Comment: I am planning to develop other applications in future which makes use of same Auth server. I use Auth server for initial authentication and access token renewal.

Comment: Also short living refresh token means, active users will be redirected to login screen often. This case I am trying to avoid.

Comment: That's the reason with OAuth2, Server side session is not needed. OAuth token represents Session just like cookie base SME.

Comment: That's comes to my 3rd question. What's your suggestion on communicating this token to client script? Since oauth2 related communication is handled at server, my client script can't get hold of any token during Auth process. Is there any way other than cookies?

Comment: Where does your client script exist? From question above there were three parties and I guess Angular JS must be producing the UI/code in Browser and logically UI/code should always talk to angular JS server which inturn should talk to Authz Server and Resource Server through backend calls apart from the first call when End User authorizes the Client App on his behalf to access the Resource Server and Client does that using Refresh token. So, in my understanding no cookie is needed in browser. Access token also stays with Angular JS Server and not in browser